# Stop zooming the content in iframe and continue scrolling the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Hi there I have an iframe. It's src is another site not mine (On this website there is  360 degree photo player that's why I use it)
I put iframe in the top of my website.
But when I scroll down the page, the content in iframe starts zooming instead of just scrolling down main page.
Do you have any ideas how to catch this scroll event and just scroll down the main page not zooming content in iframe?
do u need some demo code? or my question is clear?

Answer (score 0):

try this: (if you are using jQuery)

```
$('your_iframe_selector').scroll(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```